# Google collaborative

Tags: machine-learning, google-drive-api

I am working on a CNN program on google colab.
I am trying to run, ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory.

I want to include the dataset directory in this function. 
I have made a google drive folder "App" and in that folder I have made "dataset" Folder in which i included my dataset for training and test.

The problem is that I am not able to include this drive folder in colab for this command.

Anyone have experience of running  ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory on colab? 
How to add dataset from google drive?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [API](https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=/v2/external/notebooks/io.ipynb&scrollTo=vz-jH8T_Uk2c), this should allow you to upload files to the colaboratory venv:

```py
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()   
for fn in uploaded.keys():
  print('User uploaded file "{name}" with length {length} bytes'.format(
      name=fn, length=len(uploaded[fn])))
```

Comment: This code is to upload a file. What about already uploaded file? How can you see them. So far I have accessed uploaded files but I want to access uploaded folders. and giving them as the path of dataset for my code.

Comment: I doubt you can immediately access the drive folder where the jupyter notebook is located from within the venv.